# Pow: display development log and use Pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry, rack-pow

I really like Pow, but I think I really miss an easy way to simply display the development log somehow and also interact with a `binding.pry` console. Isn't there an easy way to do this? I know about `pry-remote`, but this just is an unnecessary additional step.

Comment: how are you doing thay?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply `tail -f log/development.log`?  That works for me with Pow (I don't use pry).  Or do you want to see the development log while using pry?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I use is to tail the pow logs. Tailing `log/development.log` is close, but does not get everything that would normally go to standard out (i.e. what you would see if you ran `rails server`).

On a Mac, the pow logs live in:

```
~/Library/Logs/Pow/apps/
```

To help remember this, I just add an alias:

```
alias kaput="tail -f ~/Library/Logs/Pow/apps/*"
```

This will tail the logs of all the apps together, which I like. But if you want a specific log just use the name of the app instead of the wildcard.

It's called `kaput` because it A) shows the things that are `puts`d and B) I have a [kapow](https://github.com/csexton/dotfiles/blob/master/home/zshrc#L295) command that restarts pow.

Comment: This is a nice solution. However, when having `rails s`, the output is colored. Is something like this supported with `tail`?

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim the colors are added when rails writes the output, since it is not attached to a terminal it strips the color codes. If you want to get colors in the log file it would be a matter of forcing color to be on.

Comment: Thank you. Let's see whether there arrive more answers. If not, I will accept your answer (though it's not 100% what I hoped for).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pry-remote](https://github.com/mon-ouie/pry-remote). [See FAQ in pry's wiki](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#pow).